# Gradle folder fills on open

Tags: android-studio, github, gradle

When i clone my github repository my gradle folder automatically fills with 3000 + files. I have a .gitignore file ignoring the .gradle folder. This results in 3000+ files needing a commit on git. No other users of the repo gets these, and their gradle folder only has few files shown in picture 1 (my gradle folder is shown in picture 2).

[image]

[image]

Its frustrating, since it leads to errors in github, when i have to commit this many files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mostly likely - the gradle home is probably set as ./gradle in your Intellij  or your login profile.

it should ideally be /Users/<>/.gradle

[image]

Comment: Thank you that solved the problem! Would never have guessed that myself.